# Minecraft can't connect to Lan: Operation Timed Out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my friend are trying to connect via a LAN world on Feed the beasts Yogscraft, and I'm pretty sure it has something to do with him being on a mac. I don't really want to start up a bukkit server or whatever server Yogscraft uses, and he is using a mac that he doesn't know the password to, so I was initially going to check the firewall to see if Minecraft was allowed through.

Is there any other suggestions? Another thing to note is that I am PC and I am unable to connect to his server when he starts it on mac (It simply doesn't show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If he is on a mac, your friend should look for a pop-up window that says: "allow incoming connections" or something similar. He should hit the allow. This will allow people to connect to his LAN world through hi s firewall/protection. it took me forever to find this because I always full screened my game. making it impossible to see.